# Testing my app on my windows phone

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, marketplace

How do I test my app on my windows mobile without paying the $99 to uploading it online? Is it possible to test my app for free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used the emulator? The next step after that would be to sign up for a developer account (for the $99 you refer to), which then lets you unlock a phone connected via Zune.

Only after that level of testing should you be considering submitting to the store for certification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to test your app for free. You just have to use the emulators provided by Microsoft.

To unlock your device as a developer device, you need to get the $99 developer account. You'll need to create that account to distribute your app anyway, so you'll have to bite the bullet one way or the other.